# what screen size in bootstrap refers to?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap. I referred to tutorial, where I come to know about screen size. What does screen size refer in bootstrap, Is it height of screen or width of screen or both or any thing other ? Apologising for such a simple, silly question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap uses different media queries to setup their grids correctly for different devices. A set **width** for different screen sizes is the breaking point for when elements should stack and such. More background information about this can be found here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/ in the Grid Introduction section.

Comment: I want to know what "screen size" refers to, does it refer to screen height or width or both ?

Comment: It refers to the width of the screen. See above answer with width in bold =).